# SSH working with router turned off. SSHing through Powerline Adapter?

Tags: ssh, router

Today I have noticed that I could continue to SSH between two (unix) computers on my private network, despite having my router turned off. I was very surprised.

After turning off my wired network on my computer (ubuntu settings), this stopped working. But even after re-turning on the wired network settings, SSH does not restart to work (saying that it cannot even connect to the network: "Activation of network connection failed").

This possibly is because my two devices are plugged to the same Powerline Adapter. Can Powerline Adapters sockets work as routers, but not configure the network, i.e. continue working for SSH as long as both computers stays connected? Otherwise what else could explain this?

Here is the model of powerline adapter I am using: https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B0746HVPMC/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o01_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1

Comment: Please try to understand what your "router" does: It (most likely) also provides a DHCP server and a nameserver. With the level of detail given, one would have to guess. So please add more details, like IP addresses, routing, name servers, etc.

Answer (score 0):

"CPL sockets" seem to be a brand of wall sockets, including both power and network sockets. Are you sure those sockets are directly wired to your router?

A typical home router often has only three or four network sockets; if you have more active network wall sockets than that, there is probably a patch panel and possibly a *network switch* somewhere.

A basic network switch would allow connectivity within the local network segment. But for automatic network configuration after a reboot, you'd need a DHCP server, which is often built into the router.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. This is actually called a Powerline Adapter. They are wired with an Ethernet cable to the wire (one of them) and to the computers (the second one). Here is the exact model I am using: https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B0746HVPMC/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o01_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1